# Which one is the best practice for choosing data type of a property in entity class Wrapper class or Primitive type in JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, wrapper, primitive

There are two options to choose the **data type** for the **property** in **entity** class either take it as **primitive data type** or keep it as **wrapper class**.

I just want to know which one is consider as **the best practice and why ?**

**Option-I**

```
@Entity
class User {

    @Id
    private int uuid;

    private long code;
    
    private boolean isActive;
    
        // setter & getter
}
```

**Option-II**

```
@Entity
class User {

    @Id
    private Integer uuid;

    private Long code;
    
    private Boolean isActive;
    
        // setter & getter
}
```

Comment: I think in any time you will need to manage Users with uuid as `null`. I prefer `Integer`,`Long` and `Boolean`

Comment: There's no hard best practice for anything but the ID, but the ID should always be nullable. (You also should not name an _integer_ property `uuid`...)

Answer (score 0):

It does not make any difference for Hibernate, as it uses the same Hibernate type to represent them.

But with primitive type you can't distinguish the default value of a primitive int 0 from an assigned 0 while there is no possible ambiguity with a null (a null id always means a new entity), which is why one should prefer to use a nullable wrapper type.